# What is wrong with this line of code? (jQuery.parseJSON)

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is wrong with this line of jQuery code?

```
jQuery.parseJSON("{ url: '/user-list.html' }");
```

I always get following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
```

Comment: key should be between double quotes

Comment: Then I'll get: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '`

Comment: run json through jsonlint.com....save a trip here to post a question

Comment: Plus the jQuery docs show you a valid example.

Comment: *"SyntaxError: Unexpected token u"* my guess is the first `u` it comes across is invalid. Once you fix that, *"SyntaxError: Unexpected token '"* use the same reasoning to realize that the first `'` is invalid. i'm sure you can guess why at that point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Object keys in JSON need to be surrounded by double quotes.

Try this:

```
jQuery.parseJSON('{"url":"/user-list.html"}');
```

Comment: Thank you!! That's the solution! I will accept your answer as soon as stackoverflow allows it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

*JSON is not JavaScript*. Basically, `{ url: '/user-list.html' }` is invalid JSON.

The [spec](http://www.json.org/) states that the 'key' portion must be a `string`, which requires double-quotes. The string values also requires double-quotes, not single-quotes.